# Why Python can't see assignments if they were made inside the scope of a function?

Tags: python, scope

Here's my code:

```
player1 = player2 = ball = score1 = score2 = None

def reset_game():
    player1 = Pad(PAD_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (PAD_HEIGHT / 2), FIRST_PLAYER)
    player2 = Pad(WINDOW_WIDTH - (PAD_WIDTH * 2), (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (PAD_HEIGHT / 2), SECOND_PLAYER)
    ball = Ball((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_SIZE / 2), (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_SIZE / 2))
    score1 = Score(((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE_SIZE / 2.8) - SCORE_SPACING * 2), SCORE_SPACING, 1)
    score2 = Score(((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE_SIZE / 2.8) + SCORE_SPACING * 2), SCORE_SPACING, 2)

reset_game()
```

I define them initially like this (I know it's a bit java-ish, but anyway), because when I press ESCAPE, I want to reset the whole game to its initial values:

```
if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
    reset_game()
```

It's pathetic to copy and paste the whole thing. Running like this, Python gives me the error:

[image]

That's because Python just can't *see* the assignment inside the function.

```
def redraw():
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    if game_screen == SINGLE_PLAYER or game_screen == MULTIPLAYER:
        draw_middle_line()
        player1.draw()
        player2.draw()
        score1.draw()
        score2.draw()
        ball.draw()
```

If I make the assignments in global scope, it works. Why Python can't see the assignments even if I "declared" as None and called the function with the assignments afterwards? (I know this is c/c++/java-ish thinking, but it makes sense nonetheless).

Comment: Local variables don't work like that. You assigned in the function, `player1` to be a local variable, if you want it to affect the global scope, call `global player1` in your function, there are better ways instead of calling `global`

Comment: Because function scope takes priority. You can use the `global` keyword to override this, but excessive use of it can lead to spaghetti code very, *very* easily. https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#global

Comment: It doesn't "make sense" nonetheless. Setting a variable is always local, unless you use the global keyword.

Comment: Don't listen to anyone who tells you to use `global`.  I will downvote them all.  You should maintain the state a different way, for example: have a `Game` object which has a `reset` method.

Comment: @wim  Thanks for the downvote ;).  I upvoted your comment anyway. I agree with your advice to avoid using globals.  I simply answered the question.

Comment: Yep, `global` is Python's closest equivalent of `goto`...if you think you need it, you're almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Man, but the script is so short. I know how people look at global as some sort of great evil, but the script is really short. There's no way I'm going to confuse myself. If I add some fancy multiplayer with 16 pads in the same pong game, then I might consider changing the design (But I'll end up doing anyway because of github and because how people look at you as an anarchist if you don't use basic conventions, like not using global in a 5 line script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that "Python can't see assignments", but simply that you didn't declare your names as global.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global

Change your function to look like this and try it:

```
def reset_game():
    global player1, player2, player3
    player1 = Pad(PAD_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (PAD_HEIGHT / 2), FIRST_PLAYER)
    player2 = Pad(WINDOW_WIDTH - (PAD_WIDTH * 2), (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (PAD_HEIGHT / 2), SECOND_PLAYER)
    ball = Ball((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_SIZE / 2), (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_SIZE / 2))
    score1 = Score(((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE_SIZE / 2.8) - SCORE_SPACING * 2), SCORE_SPACING, 1)
    score2 = Score(((WINDOW_WIDTH / 2) - (SCORE_SIZE / 2.8) + SCORE_SPACING * 2), SCORE_SPACING, 2)
```

PS.  Using global variables is very poor design.  I recommend using a different approach to organizing your program's data and code.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've read about scopes and namespaces in Python. The script for the game is quite short, so I didn't think global variables would do much harm.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = None

def foo():
    global x
    x = 10

foo()
print x #prints 10
```

Any assignment in a local scope, is considered a local variable, you need to get it from the global scope

Answer (score -1):

If you don't send variables to the function it will try to create it locally, so to allow the access it must be declared globally inside the function.

Example:

```
player1 = None

     def reset_game():
          global player1  #now you can modify player1
          player1 = Pad(PAD_WIDTH, (WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2) - (PAD_HEIGHT / 2), FIRST_PLAYER)

reset_game()
```